# Clarification needed to understand elementary combinatorics problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

10 objects are randomly distributed among 3 boxes. What is the probability to have  6 objects in one of the boxes, 3 in another one and a single object in the remaining third box.

My solution is

For the first box we have $10 \choose 6$, since 6 objects are already placed we are left with 4 remaining, so for the second box we have $4 \choose 3$ and the remaining single object is placed in the last unoccupied box. Therefore, the total number of possibilities for creating the desired distribution of object among the 3 boxes is :
$$
{10 \choose 6} \times {4\choose 3} \times {1 \choose 1}
$$

To use the probability formula I need the total number of ways to distribute 10 objects among 3 boxes.

Well, I cheated and looked in the answers section, the answer is $3^{10}$ and the probability is

$$
P=\frac{{10 \choose 6} \times {4\choose 3} \times {1 \choose 1}}{3^{10}}
$$

The question is how the $3^{10}$ can be explained. This looks like variation with repetition, but I cant really understand it.

Comment: You successfully counted the number of ways in which the situation could match the description, but to find the probability you must divide out by the total number of possible ways of distributing the objects. Thence the $3^{10}$ term.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but how the $3^{10}$ comes about.

Comment: You have 3 choices for where to put the first object (either the first box, the second box, or the third box).  Similarly you have 3 choices for each of the remaining objects.  Apply multiplication principle.

Comment: I think that this the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I would multiply by $3!$, unless we are finding the probability that a **specified** box has $6$ and another specified box has $3$.

Comment: Just to understand the principle, if I multiplied by 3! this would mean that the order of the boxes does not matter and will effectively reduce the number of all possible outcomes (I will have $\frac{3^{10}}{3!}$ in the denominator). But why only the denominator is effected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the probability of a given random event occurring, you find a ratio $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ is the number of ways the event can occur and $q$ is the total number of ways the situation can occur. You correctly discovered $p$, but forgot to account for $q$.

To see that $q = 3^{10}$, consider how we would go about placing the objects arbitrarily. We would start with the first object, and place it in one of three boxes, giving us 3 ways to do that. The second object has a similar choice, independent of where the first object went since we're making no restrictions on the situation. We repeat this for each ball. So we have 10 independent choices to make with 3 choices for each one, giving us $3 \cdot 3 \cdots 3 = 3^{10}$ ways.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but how the $3^{10}$ comes about. i.e. the size of the entire sample space.

Answer (score 1):

$3^{10}$ is simply the total number of ways in which you can distribute to the three boxes, as for each object (out of ten) you have three potential boxes in which you can put it. For each object, there are $3$ potential boxes. We have $10$ objects. Thus by the multiplication rule, we have 
$$
3 \cdot 3 \cdot  3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot .... = 3^{10}
$$
ways in total of arranging the objects.

In this question and more generally, you must divide your number of valid solutions (*which you evidently found correctly*) by your entire sample space to get your desired result.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but how the $3^{10}$ comes about. i.e. the size of the entire sample space.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had to accept the answer of walkar. He posted his answer 1 second earlier than you :)